# Using accelerator sensor android to get Direction

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I am trying to make a simple Android application, this application will get Direction when moving android device from right to left or when moving android device from Top to Button. the movement just in 2d for example android device on table or board. for example when the movement from right to left the The Left Value shell be true and right value shell False so on

Code of onCreate Method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    tvLeft= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLeft);
    tvRight= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRight);
    tvTop= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
    tvButton= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBoutton);
}
```

Code of onSensorChanged Method

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            float diffX=last_x-x;
            float diffY=last_y-y;


            Log.d("Mhd",Float.toString(diffX)+" X Diff");
            Log.d("Mhd",Float.toString(diffY)+" y Diff");



            diffX = Float.parseFloat(String.format("%1$,.1f", diffX));
            diffY = Float.parseFloat(String.format("%1$,.1f", diffY));

            if(x>last_x && Math.abs(diffX) > 0.1){

                tvLeft.setText("T");
                tvRight.setText("F");
            }else if(x<last_x && Math.abs(diffX) > 0.1){

                tvRight.setText("T");
                tvLeft.setText("F");
            }

            if(y>last_y && Math.abs(diffY) > 0.1){
                tvTop.setText("T");
                tvButton.setText("F");

            }else if(y<last_y && Math.abs(diffY) > 0.1)

                tvButton.setText("T");
                tvTop.setText("F");
            }
            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            last_z = z;
        }
}
```

Finally the program dose not gives an error 
but the generated data is not true and when the android device stable the data still 
generated.

please any idea to improve my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think about what an accelerometer is and what it does.  It's basically a force meter.  It detects a force on the device, and measures it.  It always tells you the current level of force (which will actually never be 0 due to gravity, unless you're in outer space).  It does not detect motion.  It does not return values only when moved.  It returns values every time its asked, which with SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL means every few hundred milliseconds.

The data will never be 100% correct.  The data will always have noise, because all physical sensors do.  Reverbations from old forces, mild forces due to people walking around the room, your table being not 100% steady-  the sensor will pick up all of those minor changes.  It will also be wrong by some amount each time, because they're only so accurate.  You need to look for large changes only, if you're looking for very small changes you need much better hardware than comes in phones.

Finally, it captures forces not motions.  That means if you were to move the device at constant speed, there wouldn't be any change detected-  an object at constant speed has no force applied to it.  It will only catch changes in speed-  accelerations and decelerations.  You need to look for these rather than assuming a change means its moving.  For example, moving the device left would see an acceleration to the left, followed by 0 acceletation, then an acceleration to the right (really a deceleration) as you stopped, followed by nothing.

You need to rework your whole approach.  You need much, much higher noise thresholds, and you need to look for accelerations and decelerations to determine if it is moving, otherwise your deceleration will look like a move in the wrong direction.  It's a lot more complicated than what you have here.